# hash sign comments out code when using C in terminal

Tags: c, linux, shell, terminal

I want to use #include header when writing C in linux terminal.
The hash sign comments out the code instead. Is there any way to go around this problem?

---

I use the terminal to write C code to the outer board and would need sentences like:

> ```
> echo #include "analogout.h" > analogout.c
> ```

But the hash sign # comments my code out.

Comment: It's your editor whose syntax highlighting feature is set to some other than C language.

Comment: Do you mean the compiler treats the line like a comment? Or do you mean the line looks like a comment in your editor? If the former, show the code and name the compiler. If the latter, which editor, and what is the name of your source file you are editing?

Comment: Also, if you are trying to type C code directly into your shells terminal prompt, `#` is indeed used to indicate that the rest of the text on the line is a comment.

Comment: @jxh Well, that would be an interesting turn...

Comment: I use terminal to write C code to the outer board and would need sentences like:
echo #include "analogout.h" > analogout.c
But the hash sign # comments my code out.

Comment: @GrigoryTagiltsev: You'll need to escape the `#` then, something like `echo \#include "analogout.h" > analogout.c`.

Comment: Or use a here-document.(or: an editor)

Comment: What is "outer board"?

Comment: @JohnBode, backslash worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EugeneSh., sth like raspberry pi, but custom made.

Comment: Do you mean you are writing code right on that board? Can't you do that on a computer and then transfer the files? (thanks @jxh the question is getting some shape..Retracted my close vote)

Comment: This is a question about programming, but the solution is not related to programming.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I think the outer board must be something like a daughter board attached to the motherboard. Programming occurs on the motherboard, but the code resides and compiles and runs on the daughter board.

Comment: @jxh No, I think it's just some embedded system running linux and connected to the terminal.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Why wouldn't they install BusyBox?

Comment: @jxh Not my system, not my rules :) I would rather set up an NFS and just use my favorite environment.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the string to remove the special meaning of characters:

```
echo '#include "analogout.h"' > analogout.c
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can also use this way to solve this problem:

```
echo \#include \"analogout.h\" > analogout.c
```

Comment: Avoid answering questions with `"... try this"` as asking somebody to try something and see if it works indicates that you do not have any confidence that your proposed solution is correct and they should just try it. Explain the problem and the reason why your solution worked. (I know what you meant)